# How do I prevent word cut off in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have a huge string which comes into XSLT(1.0), I have to divide this string into certain number of strings(which is a static number) with certain length (which is a static number too), but I should not allow word being cut off. For example: I have the following string

This is to test the word cut offering in printing the application PDF.

String1 with length 35 should be:
This is to test the word cut

String2 with 35 should be:
offering in printing the

String3 remaining all:
application PDF.

Please also suggest how to do in XSLT2.0 as well.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is an easy solution, using the `str-split-to-lines` template from the [FXSL library](http://fxsl.sf.net)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/"
xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
xmlns:str-split2lines-func="f:str-split2lines-func"
exclude-result-prefixes="xsl f ext str-split2lines-func"
>


   <xsl:import href="dvc-str-foldl.xsl"/>

   <!-- to be applied on text.xml -->

   <str-split2lines-func:str-split2lines-func/>

   <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:call-template name="str-split-to-lines">
        <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="/*"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pLineLength" select="64"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pDelimiters" select="' &#9;&#10;&#13;'"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="str-split-to-lines">
      <xsl:param name="pStr"/>
      <xsl:param name="pLineLength" select="60"/>
      <xsl:param name="pDelimiters" select="' &#9;&#10;&#13;'"/>

      <xsl:variable name="vsplit2linesFun"
                    select="document('')/*/str-split2lines-func:*[1]"/>

      <xsl:variable name="vrtfParams">
       <delimiters><xsl:value-of select="$pDelimiters"/></delimiters>
       <lineLength><xsl:copy-of select="$pLineLength"/></lineLength>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:variable name="vResult">
          <xsl:call-template name="dvc-str-foldl">
            <xsl:with-param name="pFunc" select="$vsplit2linesFun"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="$pStr"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="pA0" select="ext:node-set($vrtfParams)"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:for-each select="ext:node-set($vResult)/line">
        <xsl:for-each select="word">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="str-split2lines-func:*" mode="f:FXSL">
      <xsl:param name="arg1" select="/.."/>
      <xsl:param name="arg2"/>

      <xsl:copy-of select="$arg1/*[position() &lt; 3]"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$arg1/line[position() != last()]"/>

      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($arg1/*[1], $arg2)">
          <xsl:if test="string($arg1/word)">
             <xsl:call-template name="fillLine">
               <xsl:with-param name="pLine" select="$arg1/line[last()]"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="pWord" select="$arg1/word"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="pLineLength" select="$arg1/*[2]"/>
             </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$arg1/line[last()]"/>
          <word><xsl:value-of select="concat($arg1/word, $arg2)"/></word>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

      <!-- Test if the new word fits into the last line -->
    <xsl:template name="fillLine">
      <xsl:param name="pLine" select="/.."/>
      <xsl:param name="pWord" select="/.."/>
      <xsl:param name="pLineLength" />

      <xsl:variable name="vnWordsInLine" select="count($pLine/word)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="vLineLength" 
       select="string-length($pLine) + $vnWordsInLine"/>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not($vLineLength + string-length($pWord) 
                           > 
                            $pLineLength)">
          <line>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$pLine/*"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$pWord"/>
          </line>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$pLine"/>
          <line>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$pWord"/>
          </line>
          <word/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied to the following XML document**:

```
<text>
Dec. 13 — As always for a presidential inaugural, security and surveillance were
extremely tight in Washington, DC, last January. But as George W. Bush prepared to
take the oath of office, security planners installed an extra layer of protection: a
prototype software system to detect a biological attack. The U.S. Department of
Defense, together with regional health and emergency-planning agencies, distributed
a special patient-query sheet to military clinics, civilian hospitals and even aid
stations along the parade route and at the inaugural balls. Software quickly
analyzed complaints of seven key symptoms — from rashes to sore throats — for
patterns that might indicate the early stages of a bio-attack. There was a brief
scare: the system noticed a surge in flulike symptoms at military clinics.
Thankfully, tests confirmed it was just that — the flu.
</text>
```

**the wanted, correct result (the text is split into lines each not exceeding 64 characters and no word is split between two lines) is produced**:

```
Dec. 13 — As always for a presidential inaugural, security and 
surveillance were extremely tight in Washington, DC, last 
January. But as George W. Bush prepared to take the oath of 
office, security planners installed an extra layer of 
protection: a prototype software system to detect a biological 
attack. The U.S. Department of Defense, together with regional 
health and emergency-planning agencies, distributed a special 
patient-query sheet to military clinics, civilian hospitals and 
even aid stations along the parade route and at the inaugural 
balls. Software quickly analyzed complaints of seven key 
symptoms — from rashes to sore throats — for patterns that might 
indicate the early stages of a bio-attack. There was a brief 
scare: the system noticed a surge in flulike symptoms at 
military clinics. Thankfully, tests confirmed it was just that — 
the flu.
```

**Do Note**:

A transformation would typically import the xslt file that contains the `str-split-to-lines`, so the code would be much shorter.

**For completeness, here is the only imported XSLT stylesheet**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" 
>
    <xsl:template name="dvc-str-foldl">
      <xsl:param name="pFunc" select="/.."/>
      <xsl:param name="pA0"/>
      <xsl:param name="pStr"/>

      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="not($pStr)">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$pA0"/>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:variable name="vcntList" select="string-length($pStr)"/>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="$vcntList = 1">
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="$pFunc[1]" mode="f:FXSL">
                    <xsl:with-param name="arg0" 
                                        select="$pFunc[position() > 1]"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="arg1" select="$pA0"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="arg2" 
                                          select="substring($pStr,1,1)"/>
                  </xsl:apply-templates>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:variable name="vHalfLen"
                              select="floor($vcntList div 2)"/>
                <xsl:variable name="vFunResult1">
                  <xsl:call-template name="dvc-str-foldl">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pFunc" select="$pFunc"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="pA0" select="$pA0"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="pStr" 
                    select="substring($pStr,
                                      1,
                                      $vHalfLen
                                       )"/>
                  </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:variable>

                <xsl:call-template name="dvc-str-foldl">
                      <xsl:with-param name="pFunc" select="$pFunc"/>
                      <xsl:with-param name="pStr"
                                    select="substring($pStr,$vHalfLen+1)"
                                    />
                      <xsl:with-param name="pA0" 
                                select="ext:node-set($vFunResult1)"/>

                </xsl:call-template>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank You for your response! I am confused and it is complex to understand for me :( Is there a way without using any external libraries. Just with the XSLT. Thank You so much!

Comment: @user1536054: You don't need any external libraries -- I have provided the two XSLT stylesheets (files) that are used here. As for understanding -- you can *consume* this transformation without needing to understand it -- just regard it as  a black box that accepts text as input and produces the required text as output.

Comment: Thank You so much! If I want to split each line with varied length, I want to pass on the length for each line and get the output for each line. Is there a way?

Comment: Basically, I have a text comes from XML. I am trying to create an element with the sub text(length varies for each element).

Comment: Sorry, somehow, if I enter, it is posting the comment. Let me put the whole thing here:

For example, if I have a sentence like this 

"I want to create 3 elements with text lengths of 12,15,remaining text out of this whole sentence in XSLT1.0, basically this is used by the java code to stamp the PDF. In PDF, each line of text length varies and word should not be cut off in between"

So, the first element value (with 10 length) should be:
"I want to"

2nd element value (with 15 length, continuation of the first one)
"create 3 "

Comment: 3rd element will contain all the remaining

"elements with text lengths of 12,15,remaining text out of this whole sentence in XSLT1.0, basically this is used by the java code to stamp the PDF. In PDF, each line of text length varies and word should not be cut off in between"

Comment: @user1536054: Your comments contradict the text of the question. Please, edit the question, provide a complete (but small) XML document, a complete wanted result and a better explanation.